# Finding the closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let A be the set of real numbers in [0,1] which can be expressed in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n/3^n)$ where $a_n \in\{0,1\}$. By considering the sets $A_N=\big\{{x \in[0,1]: x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n/3^n), a_k \in[0,1], \forall k \leq N }\}$  or otherwise, find the closure of A. [You may assume that any $y\in[0,1]$ can be written in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b_n/3^n)$ where $b_n \in \big\{{0,1,2}\}$].

I am not sure of what to make of the hint, can someone make it slightly more explicit. Also, what definition of closure would it be best to work with (I have come across several and am not really sure what their advantages/drawbacks are). Thanks!

Comment: any real number in $[0,1]$ has a [ternary expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system); the sets $A_N$ have finite ternary expansions without the digit $2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: As I read it, $A_N$ is the set of real numbers in $[0,1)$ whose expansions have only $0$ and $1$ in the first $N$ places but can be $0,1$, or $2$ after that.

Comment: The point of the hint is to have you recognize that $A=\bigcap_NA_N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  you might be right

Comment: Would I be right in saying that I need to show that each $A_N$ is closed so A, being the arbitrary intersection of closed sets, is closed and so the closure of A is itself? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @stokes: That would work, yes.